# batch copy text file in folder month to folder day

Tags: batch-file

I have company code Folder, in the sub folder company code have month folder, in month folder have text file equal day of month (exp.folder 01 textfile = 31,folder 01 textfile = 28)

```
    0300003 Boots -------------> month  

                                (01)-----> Text file = 31 file
                                (02)-----> Text file = 28 file
                                (03)-----> Text file = 31 file
                                (..)-----> Text file = day of the month
                                (12)-----> Text file = 31 file
```

[image]

```
 0300004 AsiaBook ---------> month (01,02,03..12)
 0300005 FamilyMart --------> month (01,02,03..12)
```

I want to copy file in month folder to another day folder

```
     0300003_20170101144116.txt to c:\jan\01 
     0300003_20170102144034.txt to c:\jan\02
     0300003_20170103144748.txt to c:\jan\03
       ..........
     0300003_20170131154443.txt to c:\jan\31
```

'

```
      0300003_20170201145125.txt to c:\fab\01
      ..........
      0300003_20170228144741.txt to c:\fab\28
```

and other company

```
      0300004_20170101144255.txt to c:\jan\01
```

because i want to sum all company in every day of month

thank you for reply....

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same format for previous years, e.g.

```
X:\PathTo\2017\KPT_BU\0300003 Boots\Send\11\0300003_20171131154119.txt
X:\PathTo\2015\KPT_BU\0300005 FamilyMart\Send\09\0300005_20150915144813.txt
```

Then placing the following script in `X:\PathTo` and invoking it should create the directory and file structure you're looking for under each year, e.g.

```
%dstRoot%\2017\Nov\31\0300003_20171131154119.txt
%dstRoot%\2015\Sep\15\0300005_20150915144813.txt
```

Where `%dstRoot%` is your chosen destination for the new directory structure and copied files. *(I changed it from your initial location because typically permissions to create directories in the root of `C:` are restricted)*. You may change that location to one that suits you better on line 3, *(do not close it with a backslash)*.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "dstRoot=C:\Users\liptnait"
Set "m=JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where /R . ???????_??????????????.txt') Do (
    Set "_o=%%~dpnA"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set "_t=!_o:~-8,2!
    For /F "Tokens=1,5 Delims=\" %%B In ("!_o:%CD%\=!") Do (Set/A "_i=3*(%%C-1)"
        Call Set "_m=%%m:~!_i!,3%%"
        If Not Exist "%dstRoot%\%%B\!_m!\!_t!" MD "%dstRoot%\%%B\!_m!\!_t!"
        Copy "%%A" "%dstRoot%\%%B\!_m!\!_t!">Nul)
    EndLocal)
GoTo :EOF
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Compo, Your answer is very useful. Very close in my case.

Comment: I would appreciate it were you to accept my answer accordingly.